# Does d3.js have reverse ease functions?

Tags: d3.js

With d3.js we can achieve eased time out of normalized time t, typically in the range [0,1]

For example:

```
d3.easeCubic(0.25) = 0.0625
```

How can we reverse that, how can we find x given known y ?

```
d3.easeCubic(X) = 0.0625,
X ???
```

The answer here is cubic root, but still.

The problem is in reusability, ease function can change to `d3.easeExpIn`, or `d3.easeCircleOut, or any other, do you need to invent reverse functions on your own, or are they hidden anywhere ?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what would you use that for?

Comment: @altocumulus
I have a line chart with points at values, which is animated via curtain approach (https://bl.ocks.org/markmarkoh/8700606)
When a value is "passed" by curtain a point appears via radius transition from 0 to 4. The moment of a value being passed is
`let timeout = x(value) / width * duration`.The curtain is moved with easing, so i have to modify it like `let timeout = Math.cbrt(x(value) / width) * duration` for `d3.easeCubicIn`

Comment: I think, this can best be done using a custom tween function where you have full control over the current value of the easing. That, however, would well be worth a question in its own right. This question already has got a decent answer I fully agree with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, your math is wrong. `d3.easeCubic(0.25)` will give you `0.0625`:

```js
var easy = d3.easeCubic(0.25);
console.log(easy);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Now, back to your question:

> How can we reverse that, how can we find x given known y?

There is no native solution, but we can create our own function to find X given a known Y. The problem, of course, is that we have to invert the math for each specific easing... But, since you asked about `d3.easeCubic`, which is the same of `d3.easeCubicInOut`, let's try to create an *inverted* function for that particular easing.

First step, let's have a look at the source code:

```
export function cubicInOut(t) {
    return ((t *= 2) <= 1 ? t * t * t : (t -= 2) * t * t + 2) / 2;
}
```

You can easily see that this is the correct function, giving us the same value as the first snippet:

```js
function cubicInOut(t) {
    return ((t *= 2) <= 1 ? t * t * t : (t -= 2) * t * t + 2) / 2;
}

console.log(cubicInOut(0.25))
```

Now, let's try to invert it.

The math here is somehow complicated, but for values less than 1, here is the function:

```
function inverseEaseCubic(t){
    return Math.cbrt(t * 2) / 2;
}
```

And here is the demo. We pass `0.0625` to the function, and it returns `0.25`:

```js
function inverseEaseCubic(t){
    return Math.cbrt(t * 2) / 2;
}

console.log(inverseEaseCubic(0.0625))
```

If you want to deal with numbers bigger than 1, this is the complete function:

```
function InverseEaseCubic(t){
    return t <= 1 ? Math.cbrt(t * 2) / 2 : (Math.cbrt(2 * t - 2) + 2) / 2;
}
```

**PS:** In [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41569408/does-d3-js-has-reverse-ease-functions#comment70346048_41570057), @altocumulus just reminded us that, sometimes, it's even *impossible* to find the value. Here is a very simple example. Suppose this function:

```
function exponentiation(a){
    return a*a;
}
```

Now imagine that, when called with an unknown argument, the function returned `4`. What's the argument? Can we find out? Impossible to determine, because second degree equations, like this one, have 2 roots:

```
console.log(exponentiation(2))//returns 4
console.log(exponentiation(-2))//also returns 4
```

Comment: It further adds to the complexity of the problem that reversing the *elasticXXX*, *backXXX* and *bounceXXX* easing functions will also yield non-unique solutions.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, however it's a pity that it isn't implemented like `d3.easeCubic.inverse(0.25)`, cause there are a lot of ease functions, some of which are more complex than cubic.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado if there are 2 values, [2, -2], why not to return them as an array ?

Comment: @GerardoFurtado besides we are mostly looking for normalized values in a range of [0,1]

Comment: @user3468806 the problem is not returning an array, which is simple, but finding all possible solutions, which can be very complicated sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

I used the @Gerardo Furtado answer but the inverse function didn't work well so I wrote another

```js
function cubicInOut(t) {
  return ((t *= 2) <= 1 ? t * t * t : (t -= 2) * t * t + 2) / 2;
}
function inverseEaseCubic(x) {
  return x < .5 ? Math.cbrt(x / 4) : (2 - Math.cbrt(2 - 2 * x)) / 2;
}
  
console.log(inverseEaseCubic(cubicInOut(1)) === 1);
console.log(inverseEaseCubic(cubicInOut(0.6)) === 0.6);
console.log(inverseEaseCubic(cubicInOut(0.4)) === 0.4);
console.log(inverseEaseCubic(cubicInOut(0.1)) === 0.1);
console.log(inverseEaseCubic(cubicInOut(0)) === 0);
```